# Cannot create unordered_map of tuple<int, int, int>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

I'm using `std::unordered_map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, float>`. However, VS2010 will not compile the instantiation. I explicitly provided a `hash` specialization and an `operator==` overload. The error message refers to

```
std::unordered_map<NodeType, float> g_score;
```

And here is the full text of the error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\tuple(127): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const NodeType' to 'int'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xxtuple0(9) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Cons_node<_Ty,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&>(_Farg0 &&,_Farg1,_Farg2,_Farg3,_Farg4,_Farg5,_Farg6,_Farg7,_Farg8,_Farg9)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Car=int,
1>              _Cdr=std::tr1::_Cons_node<int,std::tr1::_Cons_node<int,std::tr1::_Tuple_type<std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil>::_Type>>,
1>              _Ty=NodeType,
1>              _Farg0=NodeType,
1>              _Farg1=std::tr1::_Nil &,
1>              _Farg2=std::tr1::_Nil &,
1>              _Farg3=std::tr1::_Nil &,
1>              _Farg4=std::tr1::_Nil &,
1>              _Farg5=std::tr1::_Nil &,
1>              _Farg6=std::tr1::_Nil &,
1>              _Farg7=std::tr1::_Nil &,
1>              _Farg8=std::tr1::_Nil &,
1>              _Farg9=std::tr1::_Nil &
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(145) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1,_Arg2>::tuple<const std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1,_Arg2>>(_Farg0 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Arg0=int,
1>              _Arg1=int,
1>              _Arg2=int,
1>              _Farg0=const std::tr1::tuple<int,int,int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(142) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base(const std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1,_Arg2> &&,float &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const NodeType,
1>              _Ty2=float,
1>              _Arg0=int,
1>              _Arg1=int,
1>              _Arg2=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(174) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const NodeType,
1>              _Ty2=float
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\unordered_map(279) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const NodeType,
1>              _Ty2=float
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\unordered_map(275) : while compiling class template member function 'float &std::tr1::unordered_map<_Kty,_Ty>::operator [](const std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1,_Arg2> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=NodeType,
1>              _Ty=float,
1>              _Arg0=int,
1>              _Arg1=int,
1>              _Arg2=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\repo\render\render\sim\simcontext.cpp(155) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::unordered_map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=NodeType,
1>              _Ty=float
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\tuple(127): error C2439: 'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Value' : member could not be initialized
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Car=int,
1>              _Cdr=std::tr1::_Cons_node<int,std::tr1::_Cons_node<int,std::tr1::_Tuple_type<std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil>::_Type>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\tuple(170) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Value'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Car=int,
1>              _Cdr=std::tr1::_Cons_node<int,std::tr1::_Cons_node<int,std::tr1::_Tuple_type<std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil>::_Type>>
1>          ]
```

Uncertain where to proceed, as I've never seen this error before. Any suggestions?

Edit: Interestingly, the `unordered_set<NodeType>` right before this compiles cleanly.

Try this for an SSCCE:

```
#include <deque>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

void GetPath() {
    typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> NodeType;
    struct node_hasher : public std::unary_function<const NodeType&, std::size_t> {
        std::size_t operator()(const NodeType& node) const {
            return std::hash<int>()(std::get<0>(node) + std::get<0>(node) + std::get<0>(node) + std::get<1>(node) + std::get<1>(node) + std::get<2>(node));
        }
    };
    std::unordered_set<NodeType, node_hasher> closed_set;
    std::unordered_map<NodeType, float, node_hasher> g_score;
    std::unordered_map<NodeType, float, node_hasher> f_score;
    std::unordered_map<NodeType, NodeType, node_hasher> came_from;
    auto node_comparator = [&](NodeType lhs, NodeType rhs) {
        return f_score[lhs] < f_score[rhs];
    };
}

int main() {
}
```

Fails to compile with the same error in the empty project. If you uncomment the `node_comparator` lambda, it works just fine. No wonder I had trouble with it- it's another VS bug.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::tuple<int, int, int>>`  I think you are missing something here.

Comment: You're specializing `std::hash<>` for a type that lives in namespace `std`?

Comment: @ildjarn: I wish to hash it and it does not come with it's own hash specialization. What else would you say I do?

Comment: You should write your own hash functor and pass that to `std::unordered_map<>` (note the 3rd and 4th template arguments); what you're trying to do now is illegal.

Comment: @ildjarn: And changing it has absolutely no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Then post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You know better than this.

Comment: When I tried `unordered_map<tuple<int, int, int>, float, myhasher> m;` (using VS 2010) it worked fine.

Comment: I'm assuming your hash-function takes a `const NodeType` object, and doesn't do anything to modify the contents of the tuple in order to generate the hash-key?

Comment: @ildjarn: Because if the error was so trivial to reproduce, I would not have done that prior to posting the question.

Comment: And yes, it's all `const`, and I know that it *should* work fine- and does, in an empty project, but not in my actual project.

Comment: See edit, which explains why I had trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the Visual C++ 2010 Standard Library.  See the following report on Microsoft Connect:

> [C++ `map<tuple<...>, V>` compilation problems](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534457/c-map-tuple-v-compilation-problems)

The bug has been fixed for Visual Studio 11.  Your example compiles without error using the Visual Studio 11 Beta.

Answer (score 2):

Hint... implement hashing and equality as lambdas, then use the type of these lambdas as template parameters:

```
auto h = [](const TKey& x) { ... };
auto eq = [](const TKey& x, const TKey& y) { ... };

std::unordered_map<TKey, TValue, decltype(h), decltype(eq)> m;
```

Comment: +1:  Unlike me, it sounds like you're testing your suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `NodeType` and `node_hasher` to namespace scope.  In C++03 local types can't be used as template arguments.  Maybe VS2010 simply hasn't implemented that change yet.  I'm simply guessing.  I don't have VS2010 and thus haven't tried this experiment with your SSCCE.

Comment: FWIW this compiles: `int main() { struct foo{}; std::vector<foo> v; v.push_back(foo()); }`. Was it just oversight that `hash` isn't defined for pairs and tuples?

Comment: Visual C++ 2010 supports usage of local types for template arguments (if it didn't, lambda expressions wouldn't work so well with the STL algorithms).  There may be bugs in this feature, but I can't recall having encountered any.

Comment: @GManNickG:  Oversight is a fair statement.  Though out-of-time is probably more accurate.  After 2009 passed with no standard in sight, the mood on the committee was very similar to that of a software project that is desperate to ship.  The committee was not willing to introduce new features unless it could be shown that not including said new feature would be disastrous.  In that time frame the amount of effort it took to get a proposal through was extremely high.  So the proposer would be working only his highest priority issues.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I'm curious if anyone has actually tried the experiment on DeadMG's code and what the outcome was.  Maybe there's a lambda/local-type/template-instantiation bug.  <shrug> or maybe not.  It was just a hunch.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thought so, makes sense.

Comment: I haven't played around much with the code, no.  But from the bug report to which i linked, it sounds like a far more general problem that occurs when using a tuple as a key type in an associative container, unfortunately.  There may be a workaround, though from Stephan's comments in response to the bug report, it doesn't sound like there are any known, easy workarounds

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Thanks for the info.  Implementing tuple without variadics, but with rvalue reference and several other C++11 features (as VS2010 does) is a total nightmare.  It isn't much of a stretch of the imagination that something unforeseen has bitten them.  It is a rough time for implementors.  I commend the VS team for the job they're doing.  And +1 for your answer. :-)

Comment: I do not envy those of you who have had to write this sort of library code that has to work with partially implemented compilers :-).  On a completely unrelated note, I am very much looking forward to your keynote (along with other sessions, of course) at _C++Now!_