# Where to implement the hash function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using an object as a key in an `unordered_map`, so I need to define a hash function. My question is, **where** should the hash function be implemented. Should I put it with the class implementation or should I implement it close to where I need it.

UPDATE:
If it makes a difference, all of this is based in a framework

Comment: can you show us what you've implemented until now?

Comment: why do you need to know that with what I am asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you anticipate you'll need to reuse it in many `unordered_map`s, put it somewhere visible, like in the class.

If you just need it for a one-off `unordered_map`, put it close to where you use it. You can even [use a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10238658/533120).

Comment: This is one case where I would *not* use a `lambda`.  You can be sure that if someone is modifying the definition of equality, it won't occur to them to track down lambdas used to instantiate `unordered_map`.  Given the dependency between the equality function and the hash function, they should be defined near one another.

Comment: @JamesKanze Err... "near" one another as in two consecutive lines of code (as illustrated in my link)?

Comment: If you're using a special equality function as well, that is a good solution.  I imagine that in a lot of cases, the equality functions will be the `oparator==` on the object type.

Comment: Tried to use the lambda but I get a compile error from the C++ library

Comment: @NebulaFox **How** did you try to use it and **what** compiler error did you get?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I stored it in a namespace, `Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'sol::gles20::resources::<lambda>`

Comment: @NebulaFox I think it would be best if you could show us a minimal self-contained code that demonstrates the problem. Just _"I stored it in a namespace"_ doesn't mean much to me. Also, which compiler are you using?

Comment: Using LLVM, `namespace space { 
auto hash = []( const TKey& x ) { /*implementation... */ };
using hashmap = std::unordered_map< TKey, TValue, decltype( hash );
}`
`TKey` implements `==` operator

Comment: @NebulaFox Hmm... my VC2010 builds that just fine. There is, however [a comparer-related bug in VC2012 STL](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727957/vc11-beta-compiler-fails-to-compile-lambda-key-comparer-for-maps-and-sets) that could possibly also affect hashes. Perhaps LLVM suffers from a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd put it with the class definition, at least if you're using `==` as
the equality function in the `unordered_map`.  The implementation of the
hash function depends on the implementation of the equality comparison,
and there is a definite advantage in keeping both together, to reduce
the probability of someone not changing the hash function if they
change `==`.

If you're also defining a special equality function for the map, then
the two functions should be defined together, probably close to where
they will be used to instantiate the map.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if the hash function is basic as below it should be method of the class and also should be inline.

```
int hashFunction(long x){
    return (int) (x % N);
}
```

If it is a little more complex hash function it should be a method of this class.Because you will need a "N" which will be spesific to that class .

Comment: According to the standard, the return type of the hash function should be `size_t`, not `int`.  And I don't see where you would normally need an `N` which depends on the class.